# Sorting tuples in F#

Tags: .net, sorting, f#

I have a list of tuples representing coordinates of points. How can I sort them by the first or second value, so that I could order my points from left to right first and from top to bottom next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want e.g.

```
myList |> List.sortBy fst
```

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.html

But tuples support structural equality and comparison, so the default sort (lexicographical) may do what you want.

Comment: sort_by was later renamed to sortBy

Answer (score 2):

Side Note:

This isn't about sorting but if your using tupled coordinates you may want to use a [Set](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.type_Set-1.html) instead of a List.  Using a Set really helped me to simplify my implementation of [Tetris](http://gradbot.blogspot.com/2009/04/tetris-in-xna-with-f.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
 let sorted = List.sort_by (fun (a,b) -> a,b) myList
```

Change the a,b if you need the other way around